# Polygon diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was earlier trying to solve a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572953/how-to-plot-a-polygon-diagram-using-matplotlib) that needs to generate this image shown below using `matplotlib`.

[image: required figure]

For that, I wrote the code, which was somewhat okay but got stuck. But I got a problem when printing segments of the circle.

Here's [my code](https://del.dog/polygondiagram.txt).

Problem is around, these lines

```
#Drawing those segments
plt.plot([14.0, 50.0],[ 50.0,86.0 ], color="black")
plt.plot([24.544155877284282, 24.54415587728429],[14.0, 50.0], color="black")
plt.plot([75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282],[24.544155877284282, 24.54415587728429], color="black")
plt.plot([83.25966317040633, 63.77660356514324],[75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282] , color="black")
plt.plot([50.0,86.0], [83.25966317040633, 63.77660356514324], color="black")
```

I got this as an output

[image: output].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Matplotlib plot [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), the `plot` function arguments, `x` and `y`, are 1-D array with x and y coordinates respectively, like `[x1, x2]` and `[y1, y2]`. So you need to swap your input coordinates from `[x1, y1], [x2, y2]` to `[x1, x2], [y1, y2]`, like:

```py
plt.plot([14.0, 50.0],[ 50.0,86.0 ], color="black")
plt.plot([24.544155877284282, 14.0],[24.54415587728429, 50.0], color="black")                          
plt.plot([75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282],[24.544155877284282, 4.54415587728429], color="black")
plt.plot([83.25966317040633, 75.4558441227157],[63.77660356514324, 24.544155877284282] , color="black")
plt.plot([50.0,83.25966317040633], [86.0, 63.77660356514324], color="black")
```

or just connect these points in a loop like:

```py
plt.plot([14.0, 50., 83.25966317040633, 75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282, 14.0], 
         [50.0, 86.0 , 63.77660356514324, 24.544155877284282, 24.544155877284282, 50.0], 
         color="black")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, got to know about the loop concept too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you group values in wrong pairs - like

```
[x1, y1], [x2, y2]
```

but it should be

```
[x1, x2], [y1, y2]
```

---

```
plt.plot([14.0, 50.0],[ 50.0,86.0 ], color="black")

#plt.plot([24.544155877284282, 24.54415587728429],[14.0, 50.0], color="red")
plt.plot([24.544155877284282, 14.0],[24.54415587728429, 50.0], color="red")

plt.plot([75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282],[24.544155877284282, 24.54415587728429], color="blue")

#plt.plot([83.25966317040633, 63.77660356514324],[75.4558441227157, 24.544155877284282] , color="green")
plt.plot([83.25966317040633, 75.4558441227157],[63.77660356514324, 24.544155877284282] , color="green")

#plt.plot([50.0, 86.0], [ 83.25966317040633, 63.77660356514324], color="yellow")
plt.plot([50.0, 83.25966317040633], [86.0, 63.77660356514324], color="yellow")
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, I did the silly mistake, Thank You, for the help.